# List of all actions protected by given permission

Tags: permissions, documentation

I am supposed to perform static analysis of an APK that has a lot of permissions requested in the Manifest.

I would like to find out whether all the permissions requested are really needed by the app to perform some action.

When I read documentation for a specific permission, it hardly mentions what actions (API calls, object initiations, broadcasts etc.) are specifically protected by that permission.

For example: When I read the docs of `READ_PHONE_STATE` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_PHONE_STATE), it never mentions the actual API calls protected by the permission. I need to google and find that the user needs this permission to call some methods of `TelephonyManager`, which is something that I can try to find in the Smali code of my APK to verify that the permission is really needed.

So my question is: Is there some documentation, website or list, where I could easily find all assets protected by various Android permissions? The documentation usually contains all permission needed by a specific call, but it does not contain all calls protected by a specific permission.

Comment: I don't think you'll find all information at one place. It's scattered over https://developer.android.com and AOSP source code. In particular Android platform's [manifest file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) can be of a little help.

Comment: In recent versions of Android the Android source code for the API used by AndroidStudio  contains `RequiresPermission` annotations on methods that specify which permissions are required to cal it. Of course there are other ways to make use of a permission that those API calls.